# Trouble with installing vs code

Tags: anaconda, visual-studio-code

I am keep getting error while installing vs code with anaconda on Ubuntu 18.04.
The error is

```
Installing Extensions ...
Server returned 503
   Unable to install python extensions for VSCode!
   Check /home/sergey/anaconda3/vscode_inst.py.log for more info
   Do you wish to retry? [yes|no]
```

Here is traceback from vscode_inst.py.log

```
ERROR:vscode_inst:installVSCodeExtenstions
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/sergey/anaconda3/pkgs/vscode_inst.py", line 281, in installVSCodeExtenstions
    subprocess.check_call(_vscode_ext_args, shell=CMD_REQ_SHELL)
  File "/home/sergey/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/subprocess.py", line 291, in check_call
    raise CalledProcessError(retcode, cmd)
subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command '['/usr/share/code/bin/code', '--install-extension', 'ms-python.anaconda-extension-pack', '--user-data-dir=', '/home/sergey/.config/Code']' returned non-zero exit status 1
```

Because of this error i cannot install any extensions on visual studio code and just keep getting "No extensions found"

Answer (score 2):

VSCode Marketplace is currently down.  When https://marketplace.visualstudio.com is back up, you should be good to go.

Answer (score 0):

you can install vscode with:

sudo snap vscode

in the terminal, but this could change some configurations in your pc.

You can see the jupyter notebook even if the vscode failed.

Answer (score 0):

Visual Studio Code should show up in the Ubuntu Software application if you search for "vscode" or it can be installed from the terminal by running the command `sudo snap install code --classic`. A snap in classic confinement behaves as a traditionally packaged application with full access to the system, and Visual Studio Code extensions are installed into the user's home directory.

Visual Studio Code is not an full featured IDE. For this reason it is not possible to create a project in Visual Studio Code, like it is in Visual Studio. On the other hand it is possible to run Python, C, C++, JavaScript, PHP, Java, R and some other programming language code blocks directly in Visual Studio Code using the Code Runner extension. Many Visual Studio extensions can also be installed in Visual Studio Code by selecting View -> Extensions and then search for the extension that you want to install.